# cakePHP scriptStart() and scriptEnd(), how to use?

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.7

why this code is not working?
Seemsm like i don't understand the usage of `scriptstart()` and `scriptEnd()`.

```
// view
<?php
  $this->Html->scriptStart(array("block"=>true,"inline"=>FALSE));
?>
$().ready(function(){
    alert("dd");
});
<?php 
  $this->Html->scriptEnd();
?>
// layout
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

**edit**

Some more info:

1. I expect it to popup the alert..
2. In the example nothing happens. seems like the javascript is not being added to the page. (i checked the source)

Comment: Be more specific... What did you expect as result, what happened the example you provided, finally, where is the script?

Comment: @Bonatti thanks for the reply. edited the question. as to the last part of your comment, this is the script. the alert.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [this documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) can help you out... Use Find and look at `$this->fetch` command

Comment: I'm here since it's not @Bonatti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the "block"=>true option, or setting it to 'script' instead:

```
// view
<?php
  $this->Html->scriptStart(array("block"=>'script',"inline"=>FALSE));
?>
    $().ready(function(){
        alert("dd");
    });
<?php 
  $this->Html->scriptEnd();
?>
```

Make sure you include the php tags in the layout:

```
// layout
<?php echo $this->fetch('script');?>
```